# Replace a space that is between a letter and a number with a comma

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Im trying to replace the following string in php:

```
2011.11.12 20:06,Teal'c Ostus,Solid Pyroxeres 46521,Pyroxeres
```

With:

```
2011.11.12 20:06,Teal'c Ostus,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
```

NOTE: There are 5 comma separated values here

```
Time, Character, Item Type, Quantity, Item Group
```

Note there are still to be some spaces left behind such as between date and time and first and last name and item with multiple words in its name.

Additionally, it cannot replace the \r and \n as there are many rows like the one above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex for Search:

```
(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2},[^,]*,\D*)\s(\d{5},.*)
```

And the regex for replace

```
$1,$2
```

**Explanation:**

*The Regex for search*

```
(       Begin a numbered capture group (Nameless and accessed via index)  
\d{4}   Means: capture digits with exact 4 repititions  
\.      Capture a dot (You have to escape it with a backslash, if not it means capture all  
        characters except linefeed)
\d{2}   Capture 2 digits
\.      Capture a dot
\d{2}   Capture 2 digits
\s      Capture 1 whitespace
\d{2}   Capture 2 digits
:       Capture a colon
\d{2}   Capture 2 digits
,       Capture a comma
[^,]*   Capture everything except a comma with 0 to infinity repititions
,       Capture a comma
\D*     Capture everything except a digit with 0 to infinity repititions
)       Close first capture group
\s      Capture a whitespace
(       Begin a numbered capture group
\d{5}   Capture 5 digits
,       Capture a comma
.*      Capture everything except a linebreak
)       Close second capture group
```

*The Regex for Replace*

```
$1      Insert capture group number 1
,       Insert a comma
$2      Insert capture group number 2
```

I hope that explains a little bit the (helpful but sometimes confusing) "magic" of regular expression. A good tool to design and test regular expressions is called Expresso and can be find [here](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). If you want an online help and regex library with expression tester, you'll find it [here](http://regexlib.com)

Comment: This worked like a charm thank you.  Do you think you could put an explanation like Narenda yadala dod so that others that read can understand (along with me)

Comment: @Wes: I've added an explanation of the regex in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  An answer like that deserves more +1s.  Thank you for the great response.

Comment: @Wes The +1s are not the only goal, someday I will have a question and need the help of others :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z_])\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+(?=[a-z_])/i', ',', $subject);
```

**Explanation**

```
                # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   (?<=            # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
      [a-z_]          # Match a single character present in the list below
                         # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
                         # The character “_”
   )
   \s              # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
      +               # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (?=             # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
      \d              # Match a single digit 0..9
   )
|               # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   (?<=            # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
      \d              # Match a single digit 0..9
   )
   \s              # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
      +               # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (?=             # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
      [a-z_]          # Match a single character present in the list below
                         # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
                         # The character “_”
   )
```

Comment: this looks like it worked except it replaced the \r \n characters as well

Comment: @Wes if you don't want that to happen then substitute `[A-Za-z_]` in place of `\D`. I edited the answer to fix the `\D` problem.

Comment: same effect.  It still gets rid of the new line characters.  I tried adding in [^\S\r\n] but then it messed up some of the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In perl you could use:

```
$line =~ s/([A-Za-z])\s+(\d)/$1,$2/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language you're using, but something like this should work:

search: `([A-Za-z]) (\d)`
replace: `\1,\2`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = "2011.11.12 20:06,Teal'c Ostus,Solid Pyroxeres 46521,Pyroxeres";
$str = preg_replace('/(\D+) (\d+)/', "$1,$2", $str);
echo $str;
```

**output:**

```
2011.11.12 20:06,Teal'c Ostus,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
```